# In CodenameOne, why is a checkbox not selected but appearing selected?

Tags: java, checkbox, codenameone, selected

I Have an odd problem - not sure if there's a coding mistake or a bug in CN1.

Basically I create a row of CheckBox objects and put them in a container that is X-Scrollable.   If i click on one un-selected item and drag until the "elastic" effect pulls it back, it appears to be selected, but the code does not record it as selected.

Please see the following video of the issue:
https://youtu.be/EtputE1kjyo

Note that in the Console output, the word 'selected' is capitalized when the field has been selected and lowercase when it is unselected.  Same for focus (I added focus to the output to determine if setFocusable() was working as desired so that focus was not to blame for the selection error).

here's the Checkbox creation code:

```
cb = new CheckBox(getCacheableImageMaxHeight(mod.getIconFile(),moduleImageHeight));
cb.setName(mod.getModuleID());
cb.setToggle(true);
cb.setUIID("ModuleButton");
cb.setFocusable(false);
cb.setScrollVisible(false);
cb.setTextPosition(Component.BOTTOM);
cb.setCloudDestinationProperty(cb.getName());

//actionlistener added for debugging only
final CheckBox cbFinal = cb;
final String modName = mod.getDisplayName();
cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(modName+", "+(cbFinal.isSelected()?"SELECTED":"selected") + ", " + (cbFinal.hasFocus()?"FOCUS":"focus"));
    }
});
c.addComponent(cb);
```

**UPDATE: I've realized there are two "states" at war here:**
The toggleButtons (I now realize they're not just CheckBoxes since I set "setToggle(true)) are getting stuck in the "pressed" state as they are dragged and released with the "elastic" effect.   Unfortunately, the "pressed" and "selected" states have the same appearance so that means my users think they have selected something when it's just stuck being "pressed" during a drag operation.

Here's some more debugging I did.
[image: Pressed AND Selected!]

- The first button is Pressed, but not selected (the bug).
- the second button is Selected normally and not showing the bug.
- The Third button is interesting because I selected it, then dragged and released it to get it to be SELECTED and PRESSED!

So the question changes to: **Is there an open bug for this situation already (Pressed state gets stuck on after button is released) and if so, is there a fix coming or a workaround for now?**

Comment: I think it's  because `CheckBox` is set to act as a `ToggleButton` and your click to drag for scrolling stays a little bit too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a more effective workaround that doesn't involve adding a separate pressed style (since there could be buttons selected, pressed, and selected+pressed with the bug)

I needed to capture the event that scrolling stopped and then check the state of the buttons to make sure none were still pressed.  To do this, I used `addPointerReleasedListener` on the scrolling container to detect when the pointer came off (so its components are definitely no longer pressed), and then in its `Runnable`, I make sure each one is released.

```
scrollingContainer.addPointerReleasedListener(evt -> {
    Container cont = (Container) evt.getComponent();
    Iterator<Component> buttons = cont.iterator();
    while (buttons.hasNext()){
        Button button = (Button) buttons.next();
        if (button.getState() == Button.STATE_PRESSED) {
            button.released();
        }
    }
});
```

So far seems to solve the problem.  Now we just need a permanent fix, or a note in the documentation of `ToggleButtons` that when they are in a scrolling container, they could get stuck in a pressed state and need to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Just style the selected state to look different from the pressed state and it should work fine.

In a touch device selected state isn't rendered when the finger is up. This is almost always true unless you changed a flag in `Display` or set some arcane theme constant.

Comment: I guess that is a workaround, although I would probably have to style "pressed" to look like "unselected" so that it doesn't get confusing (some elements would look selected and others would look pressed confusing them...).  Then that would mean there's no visual feedback to the user on when something is pressed..    I found my own workaround that I'll post, but I'm hoping this is actually considered a bug and will get addressed...  should I add a bug to the project?

Comment: No. It's the other way around. Pressed should have a pressed look, selected is more open to interpretation. I'm not sure I see a bug here.

Comment: The bug, in my opinion, is that after lifting my finger, the button is still in a pressed state.  If that isn't a bug, can you please help me understand when I'd use that behavior? Maybe I'm trying to use toggle buttons incorrectly?

Comment: That's the functionality of Toggle Buttons. They stay pressed, otherwise they would be just regular buttons.

Comment: ok, that wasn't clear to me.  Is there somewhere that describes the relationship between  a toggle button, the selected state and the pressed state and how to interpret them correctly in an app?   Personally, I thought that the state indicating they are "toggled" is selected, not pressed.   That is what would make most sense to me by the names:  "pressing" something is transient, and only happens while my finger/pointer is down and is cleared when it goes up.  The persistent state to look for in my app to indicate it's "toggled on" would be that it is Selected. that's how I See the two relate.

Comment: That's totally our fault. When we started LWUIT we used selected to mean focused which was a HUGE mistake and we should have fixed it back then. Unfortunately we didn't and in the case of checkboxes/radio buttons selected has a double meaning... The problem with mistakes like that is that it's just not feasible to fix them by now.